# Relation between work function and depth of electron (inside the metal)

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Dose the work function depend on the position of electron inside the metal (depth of electron inside the metal)?

Comment: [Relevant](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/459517/is-photoelectric-effect-a-surface-phenomenon)